# Why does my Windows 10 Home have Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a laptop with Windows 10 Home preinstalled and activated successfully. But it contains Remote Desktop and BitLocker functionalities. It is said in many sources that Home edition of Windows 10 lacks Remote Desktop and BitLocker.

Is there anything different in OEM versions?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that Windows 10 Home actually can mount volumes encrypted by Bitlocker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the Remote Desktop *client*. That comes with all editions of Windows that I'm aware of. Therefore, you can remotely log into to other machines that support it. Your computer does not, however, have the *server* part of Remote Desktop, so you can't remote into your machine from anywhere else. The server part only comes with Pro and Enterprise editions of Windows (and the Windows Server OSes).